# Excel reads "64E0113" style codes as a number "6.4E+114" even when formatted as text

Tags: vba, excel

When reading a csv file containing ID numbers, excel is reading strings as numbers. This also occurs when reading the same style of ID's in an excel vba array.

[image: Under locals, the elements of the array are displayed as datatype "String", but the format is still a number.]

Under locals, the elements of the array are displayed as datatype "String", but the format is still a number.

I have tried changing the style to text as well as using CStr() on individual elements of an array. Is there a way to have excel read the ID's as a string instead of a number?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say it's reading the value as a number, do you mean it's storing it as a number in memory? Or, put differently, when does Excel convert it to a number? Is it when the value is added to a worksheet?

Comment: When opening the csv file, or when reading the value from an array. When typing it into excel it also converts it to a number unless specifically formatted as text. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You can prefix with a quote `'` when typing to avoid interpretation, I think the same trick can be used in VBA

Comment: Yes. @Gary's Student has a suitable answer below if you're Importing the file. Otherwise, you would have to format the range as Text (which can also be done with VBA in case it's a VBA solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert back this might suit:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,3),".","")&"E"&TEXT(RIGHT(A1,3)-1,"0000")
```

Comment: This method works for both the array and when importing. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to bypass the automatic conversion when you open the *.csv* file.

Use the *Import Wizard* to open the file and tell the *Wizard* that the field is text.

[image]